# integration question on

Tags: calculus

> For a certain drug, the rate of reaction in appropriate units is given by
>   $R'(t)=\dfrac{4}{t+1}+\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{t+1}}$ Where $t$ is time (in hours) after the drug is administered. Calculate the total reaction to the drug for the first $12$ hours.

**My attempt:**

Integrate $R'(t)$ and get: $4\ln(t+1) + 6\sqrt{t+1}$ however stuck on the bounds and if this is correct

Comment: You need to evaluate, $$\int_{0}^{12} R'(t) dt$$

Comment: Is it from 1 to 12 or 0 to 12?

Comment: Is it from 1 to 12 or 0 to 12 as the bounds?

Comment: Time starts at $t=0$

Comment: Thank you. I think I get it now, but can you include a solution here for completeness? I want to verify my answer, that's why

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. The bounds of the integral are $0$ and $12$. Apart from the fact that time usually starts at $t = 0$, consider this: if it were only one hour, it would be from $0$ to $1$ (and $1 - 0 = 1$). Similarly, for $12$ hours it is:
$$\int_0^{12} R'(t)\,\mathrm dt = 4\ln(t + 1) + 6\sqrt{t + 1}\,\bigg|_0^{12} = 4\ln{13} + 6\sqrt{13} - 6$$